# cifs mount without owner or permissions on RHEL8 (but fine with RHEL7)

Tags: rhel, cifs, smb

So on RHEL8, I'm connecting to an Isilon storage appliance via CIFS.  The mount options in fstab are `rw,vers=2.1,nobrl,credentials=*****,uid=sviibtst,gid=mqbrkrs,dir_mode=0770,file_mode=0770,_netdev.`

When it mount successfully, the mount point looks... odd.

```
ls: cannot access '/mnt/iib': Invalid argument
total 0
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root  29 Jul 21 11:11 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root root 256 May 27 16:32 ..
d??????????  ? ?    ?      ?            ? iib
```

I have the exact same options on a RHEL7 server and when mounted and I see:

```
total 32
drwxr-xr-x. 12 root     root    4096 Mar  8 15:00 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root     root    4096 Feb 18  2020 ..
drwxrwx---.  2 sviibtst mqbrkrs    0 Jun  3 13:47 iib
```

When I issue the mount command on RHEL7 and see all the options the system applies to this cifs share:
//esbfs/iib on /mnt/iib type cifs `(rw,relatime,vers=2.1,cache=strict,username=*****,domain=*****,uid=5003,forceuid,gid=584,forcegid,addr=********,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,nobrl,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)`

uname -a: Linux rhel7.local 3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 26 20:18:08 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

On RHEL8 I get:
//esbfs/iib on /mnt/iib type cifs `(rw,relatime,vers=2.1,cache=strict,username=*****,domain=*****uid=5003,forceuid,gid=584,forcegid,addr=**********,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,nobrl,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,_netdev)`

uname -a: Linux rhel8.local 4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 3 03:12:15 EST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Now; if I change RHEL8 to use vers=1.0 the mount point appears fine after mounting.  Obviously, I don't want to leave it like that.  The output of
dmesg doesn't show any errors either when not having vers=1.0 in the options

I'm connecting to the servers with the same username/domain/password combination.